# listening to events on a website using php and/ javascript

Tags: php, javascript, listener

I am looking to see if such a scenario is possible -

1. My website hosts couple of mp3 files. The URL would look like www.abc.com/.mp3 .
2. Assume that I get an incoming request from a user on iOS/android, using his browser to access my mp3 link above

My question is, can i listen to the event (that of my website mp3 being accessed) and then send send another mp3 to the user?

I am looking at using PHP and javascript, maybe, to do this. Please direct me on the approach to do this.

Comment: I think .htaccess can serve you...

Comment: any framework you using ?

Comment: no, I quite open to any technology. I can use any framework that supports this.

Comment: @Akam - Could you please elaborate a little bit more on how to use .htaccess to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use php or javascript as said in your question, I can imagine two solutions for you problem on client side (javascript) or server side (php) :

- On client side, using javascript, you can wrap the call to the mp3 in a javascript function (maybe by ajax). This function will check the browser and depending on it get the proper mp3
- On server side, using php, you may wrap the mp3 query in a PHP script, say getmp3.php?file=xxx.mp3. Your client page will not get the mp3 directly but ask it to this php script. This script will check User Agent and send the mp3 with something like :

  ```
  // Get the asked mp3
  $askedfile = _GET['file'];

  // Get browser info 
  $browser = get_browser(null);

  // Put filename to the proper mp3 file depending on the browser
  $filename = ...;

  // Put the proper content/type :
  header('Content-Type: audio/mp3');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="$askedfile"');
  header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));

  // Send the mp3
  readfile($filename);
  ```